# Strange "disappearing" CPU utilization

Tags: c, multithreading, cpu-usage

It's an odd title, but bear with me.  Some time ago, I finished writing a program in C with Visual Studio Community 2017 that made significant use of OpenSSL's secp256k1 implementation.  It was 10x faster than an equivalent program in Java, so I was happy.  However, today I decided to upgrade it to use the bitcoin project's libsecp256k1 optimized library.  It worked out great and I got a further 7x performance boost!  Changing what library was used to do the EC multiplications is the ONLY thing I changed about the software- it still reads in the same input files, computes the same things, and outputs that same results.

Input files consist of 5 million initial values, and I break that up into chunks of 50k.  I then set pthreads to use 6 threads to compute those 50k, save the results, and move on to the next 50k until all 5 million are done (I've also used OpenMP with 6 threads).  For some reason when running this program on my Windows 10 4-core laptop, after exactly 16 chunks, the CPU utilization drops from 75% down to 65%, and after another 10 chunks down to 55%, and so on until it's only using about 25% of my CPU by the time all 5 million inputs are calculated.

The thread count (7- 1 main thread, 6 worker threads) remains the same, and the memory usage never goes over 1.5GB (laptop has 16GB), yet the CPU utilization drops as if I'm dropping threads.  My temps never go over 83C, and all-core turbo stays at the max 3.4Ghz (base 2.8), so there is no temp throttling happening here.  The laptop is always plugged in and power settings are set to max performance.  There are no other CPU- or memory-intensive programs running besides this one.

Even stranger is that this problem doesn't happen on either of my two Windows 7 desktops- they both hold correct CPU utilization throughout all 5 million calculations.  The old OpenSSL implementation always stayed at correct CPU utilization on all computers, so something's different yet it only affects the Windows 10 laptop.

I'm sorry I don't have code to demonstrate this, and maybe another forum would be more appropriate, but since it's my code I thought I'd ask here.  Anyone have any ideas what might be causing this or how to fix it?